# Accessing multiple servers

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

At my place of work some... changes are being done that will require us to log into multiple servers, 4 of them, but won't be able to use RSAT due to a lack of admin rights on the new computers.

Any ideas or solutions for not needing 4 different windows for the servers due to various inconveniences involved.

Comment: Do an RDP into another machine which you have admin access to run RSAT or or install such tools from there. A machine where the RSAT accessible tools in your AD is available for you to SHIFT+right-click run as other user, or whatever options are accessible... Look to see where PowerShell is accessible and see if learning and getting a "new" PS method for certain things would be work the time figuring it out.... Quick thoughts.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that'll work because we only have admin rights on computers, not the servers we'd be rdping into. Dang...

Comment: What specific RSAT modules or components do you need to access? Like DNS, DHCP, AD Users and Computers, etc, etc.... Perhaps there are other ways to access these modules for what you need specifically rather than having all tools available via the RSAT components (i.e built-in and has a remote connect component or command). If you do have local admin rights to "computers" then install RSAT on those client machines which is what RSAT is typically for anyway so you don't need to access these via a domain controller. If PowerShell is already installed, you should be able to access it to run.

Comment: Specifically the remote desktop .MSc option.